# Check if an integer is non positive number, fast as possible

Tags: c

I want to check if a value of a variable X is non positive as fast as possible.
so let X be an integer return X if X is a positive number, otherwise return 0.

I have written the following macro but I feel like there is a faster way of doing so.

```
#define negX(X) ((X) > 0 ? X : 0)
```

Thank you for assisting.

Comment: That's fine, the compiler will optimize as good as you can. The alternative `if (x >> 31) /* x is a negative int */` is the basic way of checking a 4-byte `int` for the sign-bit being set. (being readable should be your main goal and then let the compiler do its job)

Comment: Just brainstorming ... `(X) * ((X) > 0)`??? check your speed testing

Comment: That's likely to be better than anything else you try -- any reasonable compiler will compile that to a [test + conditional move](https://godbolt.org/z/qGKq1cjob)

Comment: Why does it need to be "as fast as possible"? What is your use-case? Have you measured and profiled that your check is one of the top-two bottlenecks in your algorithm? Did you build with optimizations enabled for the measuring and profiling? My gut feeling is that you're attemting a premature micro optimization that will most likely not be better than plain `if (x <= 0)` (or similar).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think it's obvious it should be as fast as possible in order  to not to waste computational resources. But it should be primarily the task of compiler writers to exploit these tricks to the benefit of the largest possible audience. I would definitely go for bithacks in critical loops, even when facing the risk of code-rot: too clever code may produce also unexpected results (regression) with the next compiler upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest sequence is actually an architecture specific optimization: given that the architecture supports it, one can express the conditional clearing of negative values by

```
int32_t clear_negative(int32_t a) {
    return a & (a >> 31);
}
```

This could be expressed in modern IA assembly as

```
mov eax, 31
sarx eax, edi, eax
andn eax, edi
```

Or in Armv8 architecture as

```
bic     w0, w0, w0, asr #31
```

Clang actually selects

```
mov     eax, edi
sar     eax, 31
andn    eax, eax, edi
```

possibly because the `mov` and `sar` operations are shorter than `mov reg, #imm` and `sarx` and a register transfer is likely to fuse with the upcoming `sar`.

This happens even in a complex sequence as in

```
int32_t a(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c) {
    return clear_negative(a) + 
           clear_negative(b) + 
           clear_negative(c);
}
```

where I would have expected the compiler to generate the `mov ecx, 31` since it would save instructions and it would share the same constant three times. It can be a missed optimisation or the optimiser can have a better cost model than me.

Altering with clang versions in godbolt it becomes obvious that clang-13-trunk (for x86) knows this shifting hack to be equal to conditional clearing of negative, where as clang-13.0 does not.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is very good at optimizing your code. As shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KK6fP86nP), there is no difference between using greater-than and bitwise AND. `!(num & 0x80000000) ? num : 0;`
and `num > 0 ? num : 0;` both compile to

```
xor     eax, eax
test    edi, edi
cmovns  eax, edi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the bitwise operator:
Note:- Assuming that 32-bit machine.

To determine the sign of a number we can check the MSB(Most Significant Bit) bit of the number.
`#define sign(x)  ((((x) & 0x80000000) == 0)?x:0)`

The binary representation of `0x80000000` is `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

For a positive number, the MSB bit is `0` otherwise `1` for negative.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIGN(x)  ((((x) & 0x80000000) == 0)?x:0)
int main(void){
    printf("%d",SIGN(9));
}
```

Or

You can define macro as below.

`#define sign(x)  (((x) & 0x80000000)?0:x)`